# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

Estou com problema na variável id do meu dataGridView, ela está dando o seguinte erro: "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto Visual Studio". Estou usando Windows Form, MySQL e o DataGridView. Segue o código:

```
//Declarando variaveis globais
    int id;
    private MySqlConnection cone = new MySqlConnection();
    private MySqlCommand comandoSql = new MySqlCommand();
    private MySqlDataReader dados;
    public frmGerenciarClientes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Mapeando evento de seleção de celulas da tabela
        //dgvClientes.CellMouseUp += dgvClientes_CellMouseUp;
    }
    private void dgvClientes_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["cod_cli"].Value.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = cone.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from clientes where cod_cli=" + id + "";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            txtIdALT.Text = dr["cod_cli"].ToString();
            txtNome1.Text = dr["nome_cli"].ToString();
            txtEndereco.Text = dr["end_cli"].ToString();
            txtNum.Text = dr["endnum_cli"].ToString();
            txtBairro.Text = dr["bairro_cli"].ToString();
            txtCidade.Text = dr["cid_cli"].ToString();
            mtxtCel.Text = dr["cel_cli"].ToString();
            mtxtTel.Text = dr["tel_cli"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dr["email_cli"].ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que é o `id`? Esse erro acontece quando você tenta acessar uma propriedade/método de um objeto nulo, mas id é um int (não possuem nulo).

Comment: Então, o erro ocorreu na linha: `id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["cod_cli"].Value.ToString());`

Comment: Certamente seu .Cells["cod_cli"] esta NULL, quando você tenta acessar seu Value vai acontece esse erro.o que você pode fazer é verificar com um breakpoint qual o valor passado nessa linha.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme comentado, este erro acontece quando se tenta acessar uma propriedade/método de um objeto nulo. Como a exceção está ocorrendo na linha

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["cod_cli"‌​].Value.ToString());
```

Verifique qual dos componentes desta expressão está nulo:

- Veja se `dgvClientes` está nulo; Caso contrário
- Veja se a expressão `dgvClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex]` retorna nulo; Caso contrário
- Veja se a expressão `dgvClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["cod_cli"‌​]` retorna nulo. Caso Contrário
- Veja se a expressão `dgvClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["cod_cli"‌​].Value` retorna nulo.

Se não for nenhum deles então ainda não encontramos o problema real.